# zsh error: export:54: not valid in this context:

Tags: shell, terminal, zsh

While messing around with zsh today and getting something configured properly for ruby, I got the following error.

```
/Users/secallahan/.zshrc:export:54: not valid in this context: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/texbin
```

Here is my .zshrc (around line 54, where the error occurs) file that I edited.

```
# Path to your oh-my-zsh configuration.
ZSH=$HOME/.oh-my-zsh

....
....

# User configuration

export $PATH=/Users/secallahan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin:/Users/secallahan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/bin:/Users/secallahan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin:/Users/secallahan/.rvm/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/texbin
# export MANPATH="/usr/local/man:$MANPATH"
```

This was the only way I was able to make it. So then I opened a new shell and did `ruby -v` and got ruby2.1.1 as the current version.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: FYI, you don't need to use `export` when updating `PATH`, since `PATH` will universally have the export flag set already. `export` is only needed when marking a variable for export which didn't have the flag previously set.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

When defining or exporting a variable, you should not use `$`:

```
export PATH=/Users...
```

Otherwise, the current value of `PATH` will be substituted into the `export` statement.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense. That worked perfectly, thanks! Just to spin off another question form that, what exactly does the `$` do?

Comment: it means "use the variable's value"... e.g. `echo PATH` outputs the word "PATH", `echo $PATH` outputs the value of the PATH variable.

Answer (score 3):

This can also be caused by using pasted incorrect double quotes for your value
To fix it delete your double quotes and type them in terminal

For example:

```
export CPPFLAGS=“-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/include”
```

is wrong and needs to be:

```
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/include"
```

Answer (score 1):

You left out the double quotes too.
This was my case, I had to change the syntax from

```
export PATH=/usr/local/opt/node@12/bin/  to

export PATH="/usr/local/opt/node@12/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I ran `source .env` command. The reason was space between double quotes and equals to.

`export API_KEY= "#####"`

Fixed it by removing space.

`export API_KEY="#####"`